# Store OSGI command output into variable using Bash Script

Tags: bash, osgi

I'm completely new to bash scripting. My problem is to store the output of an OSGI command into a variable or directly into a .txt file using a bash script:

```
$   osgi
$   version
fw verion: xxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
```

I activate OSGI and have to type "version" then I get a few lines of output and I want to store this output into a variable or directly into a .txt file (to check later whether I have the right version with `grep "fw version: xxx" file.txt` and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You can run Your osgi command and put " > file.txt" without quotes at the end that would redirect output to file

Comment: Hi, I added a comment to the upper response

Comment: @R. Lattner then try in batch:
1: $(var)=`osgi command`
2: echo $(var)
Sorry - could not split code in to 2 lines :)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output of a command to a variable like this:

```
$ var=$(date)

$ echo $var
Thu Apr 14 16:02:41 CEST 2016
```

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your response, if I try it that way, it won't work, because if I type "osgi" it's like going into a new mode and i can't use bash commands there. So if I type something like "  osgi && version " into the command window, it just switches to the osgi mode, like he is ignoring the "version" command. If i try to use bash commands in that mode he will just show me the available osgi commands like "version; config.xxx etc."

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `osgi` command you are using, but it seems to be interactive, like `dc` for example. So I assume it will read from stdin like a well-behaved program should: `var=$(echo "3 4 + p" | dc)`, or, in your case, `version=$(echo version | osgi)`.